# Brute-Force password cracker with no extra modules not working properly

Tags: python

```
# Gets Input Values
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
length = 0
intCorrent = ""
looping = True
# Sets Loop To Restart If Input Isn't An Int
while looping:
    try:
        # Gets User Input For Length And Stops Loop If it's An Int
        print('Enter The Maximum Length:')
        length = int(input())
        looping = False
    except ValueError:
        # Runs If Input Isn't An Int
        print('You Did Not Type A Number')
# Gets Input, Neatens It And Turns It Into A List
print('Type Letters You Wish To Use')
letters = sorted(set([i for i in input() if i != " "]))

# ⫷-----------------------------------------------⫸


def main(max, num, a):
    if num == max:
        print("".join(a), 1)
    elif num == 0:
        for i in letters:
            a += i
            main(max, num+1, a)
            a = []
    elif num > 0:
        for i in letters:
            a += i
            main(max, num+1, a)
            a = a[:-1]

main(length, 0, [])
```

I tried to make a brute force password cracker without modules, using custom length aswell, ik it's pretty bad atm but I'm just trying to get it to work first, it adds an extra letter at some point in the code, which I don't want, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it adds an extra letter? Can you figure out where it probably does so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call the recursion from the same variables sometimes.

Look at this part of the code:

```
        for i in letters:
            a += i
            main(max, num+1, a)
```

When you write `a += i` you are not actually creating a new list but extending the old one. Python will iterate through the string `i` and extend the list `a`. So you put the same `a` in the next call of `main`. In this next call you extend `a` by `i` and call `main` again. And so on.

Here is a fixed version of your function:

```
def main(max, num, a):
    if num == max:
        print("".join(a))
    elif num == 0:
        for i in letters:
            a += i
            main(max, num+1, list(a))
            a = []
    elif num > 0:
        for i in letters:
            a += i
            main(max, num+1, list(a))
            a = a[:-1]
```

Btw there is a way to generate the words without a recursion:

```
WORD_LENGTH = 3
ALPHABET = 'abcdef'

total_words = len(ALPHABET) ** WORD_LENGTH

for word_code in range(total_words):
  chars = []
  for _ in range(WORD_LENGTH):
    next_char_index = word_code % len(ALPHABET)
    word_code //= len(ALPHABET)
    chars.append(ALPHABET[next_char_index])
  word = "".join(chars)
  print(word)
```

Comment: wow, thanks, exactly what i needed, im just going to read through it all to understand it